# Hoare partition correctness

Tags: c

according to introduction to algorithms I wrote a code for quicksort using Hoare's partition in the codeblocks IDE .The code was successfully built but the sorted array is not displayed on the console,only the unsorted array is displayed followed by a blinking underscore.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
int partition(int arr[],int p,int r)
{
    int i,j,x,temp;
    x=arr[p];
    i=p-1;
    j=r+1;
    while(true)
    {
        do{
            j=j-1;
          }while(arr[j]<=x);
        do{
            i=i+1;
          }while(arr[i]>=x);
        if (i<j)
        {
            temp=arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[j];
            arr[j]=temp;
        }
        else
            return j;
    }

}
void quicksort(int arr[],int p,int r)
{
    if (p<r)
    {
        int q=partition(arr,p,r);
              quicksort(arr,p,q-1);
              quicksort(arr,q-1,r);
    }
}
void print(int A[],int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        printf("%d ",A[i]);
}
int main()
{
    int arr[]={1,12,56,2,67,0,98,23};
    int size=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    printf("\nthe array is\n");
    print(arr,size);

    quicksort(arr,0,size-1);
    printf("\nthe  sorted array is\n ");
    print(arr,size);
    return 0;
}
```

the output was as follows

```
the array is
1 12 56 2 67 0 98 23
```

`

Comment: What did you do after you found it didn't work? Have you made any attempt to debug it? The best way is to step through your code in a debugger. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You probably have an infinete loop. Again, using a debugger will instantly tell you which loop it is stuck in. And then you can go ahead and look at the variable values as well as step the code to see exactly what it is doing.

Comment: I get a segfault and the stack traceback is an infinite number of calls with `quicksort(...,p=0,r=1)`

Comment: MSVC gives continual recursion until stack overflow.

Comment: You're doing `quicksort(arr,p,q-1); quicksort(arr,q-1,r);` but I think it should be: `quicksort(arr,p,q-1); quicksort(arr,q+1,r);` [from wikipedia]

Comment: Now it doesn't crash, but is not correctly sorted either.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I refactored your algorithm, based on a guide from wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

As mentioned in my comment above, the [recursive] `quicksort` calls used the wrong arguments. But, then, as Weather Vane mentioned, it [still] didn't sort.

**Edit:** My original post was using Lomuto partitioning instead of Hoare.

The `partition` algorithm differed from the wiki by using a different initial value for the pivot and using `<=,>=` on the `do/while` termination conditions instead of `<,>`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int
partition(int arr[], int p, int r)
{
    int i,
     j,
     x,
     temp;

    x = arr[(p + r) / 2];

    i = p - 1;
    j = r + 1;

    while (1) {
        do {
            i += 1;
        } while (arr[i] < x);

        do {
            j -= 1;
        } while (arr[j] > x);

        if (i >= j)
            return j;

        temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
}

void
quicksort(int arr[], int p, int r)
{
    if (p < r) {
        int q = partition(arr, p, r);
        quicksort(arr, p, q);
        quicksort(arr, q + 1, r);
    }
}

void
print(int A[], int size)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
}

int
main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 12, 56, 2, 67, 0, 98, 23 };
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    printf("\nthe array is\n");
    print(arr, size);

    quicksort(arr, 0, size - 1);
    printf("\nthe  sorted array is\n ");
    print(arr, size);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```